# rxjs operator that adds logging before and after a callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to turn this:

```js
/* ...inside a pipe */
tap(() => logData('my process')),
tap(() => someCallback()),
tap(() => logDataEnd('my process'),
/* pipe continues */
```

Into a new operator that takes the callback `() => someCallback()` and adds the logging side-effects before and after it. My logging functions use `performance.now()` and they work as expected* when I just use the explicit `tap` version, but none of my operators do the same thing.

**Expected Results**

A pipe using my operator:

```
of(null).pipe(
  withLogging(() => callbackA()),
  withLogging(() => callbackB()),
  /* etc. */
)
```

should produce a log that looks like this:

```
Action A start
Action A end
Action B start
Action B end
...
```

However I'm getting this:

```
Action A start
Action B start
/* ... rest of the pipe */
Action A end
Action B end
```

By looking at the timestamps I can see that the `end` logs are timestamped correctly but the `begin` ones are too early.

I've tried using `defer` in different ways but the outcome doesn't change.

**What I've tried**

```js
withLogging<T, R>(project: (value :T) => R): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
  defer(() => of(startLogging())).pipe(
    flatMap(() => source),
    tap(() => stopLogging())
  );
}
```

I've tried wrapping the entire pipe with a `defer` or just the start of the logging process, or doing `of(null).pipe` and then putting all of the effects together. I've even tried not using `defer` at all and just returning a pipe starting with `null`. Nothing has produced the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your `someCallback()` is itself asynchronous and/or you would want to flatMap it in the future, I wouldn't implement a new operator here. A simple vanilla higher order function will do what you need nicely.

```
function withLogging<A extends unknown[], C>(
  cb: (this: C, ...args: A) => void
) {
  return function(this: C, ...args: A) {
    console.log("before");
    cb.call(this, ...args);
    console.log("after");
  };
}

// snip

function someCallback() {
    console.log('Hello!');
}

someObs$.tap(withLogging(someCallback)); // before, Hello!, after for each pushed element
```

Comment: This is working as intended, and is much simpler to understand than whatever I was trying. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up: If `cb` returns an observable, can I check that and then `pipe(tap(log)))` rather than logging after the callback? This will allow me to measure the time for the entire async process rather than just the function call.

Comment: Doesn't sound too difficult to implement, although I'll admit my rx is very rusty.